# How do I configure a WCF service to run with PerCall instance context?

Tags: wcf, instancecontextmode

Here's the background info. I have a WCF service configured like so

```
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

Now I need some help understanding exactly how this context mode works.

Here's the problem I'm dealing with. For the sake of argument, lets say I have a call that takes 10 seconds to execute and return from the server. If I make two calls simultaneously (using Ajax request), the first request will come back after 10 seconds. But the second request will come back after 20 seconds.

I was expecting that this context mode would process both requests independent of each other, and return both at the same time. Have I configured my service properly?

Answer (score 1):

In `PerCall` each call is assigned a separate instance (*for extreme scalability*). Every call to the method results in a new server object being created (*separate thread*). Once the request has been processed (*method returns*), the new instance is released.

If you had configured the method to use `ConcurrencyMode.Single` then you would see this blocking behavior.

You should consider reviewing the [`serviceThrottling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) configuration to ensure that your application is tuned properly.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="throttleBehavior">
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="15" maxConcurrentInstances="10"/>
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]

may not always create service contexts immediately for each call. If the binding that is used is session enabled and the service implements IDispose, then a client call will be queued while there is already a service instance for another client. So, check binding details in your case.